# Cannot send to @component data from @page ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I trying to communicate from @Page to a @Component with a simple string but value is always undefined - cannot understand what im doing wrong here.

Code..
@Page

```
<createnewqueueitem [qId]="currentQueueId"></createnewqueueitem>

import {CreateItemPage} from '../create-item/create-item';
import {iQueue, iQueueItem} from '../../models/queue';
 import {QueueHeader, contentHeaders } from '../../common/headers';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/queue-info/queue-info.html',
  directives:[CreateItemPage]
})
export class QueueInfoPage {

  queueItem: iQueueItem;
  objQueue:iQueue;
  currentQueueId:number;
  currentQueueName:string;
  queues: any;
  constructor(public nav: NavController, private navParams: NavParams,          private queueService: QueueService) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.navParams = navParams;


    this.queueItem = <iQueueItem>this.navParams.get('queueItem')
    console.log(this.navParams.get('queueItem'));
    this.currentQueueId = this.queueItem.id;
    this.currentQueueName = this.queueItem.name;

    this.queueService.fetchQueue(this.currentQueueId).then(data => {
      this.objQueue = data;
      this.queues = this.objQueue.items;
      console.log(data);
      // this.queues(data);
    });
  }

  createItem(queueId){
    this.nav.push(CreateItemPage, {
      queueItemId: queueId
    });
  }

}
```

This is my @Component

```
    import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'createnewqueueitem',

  template: `

  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      ADD ITEM TO QUEUE
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Item name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
      {{qId}}
    </ion-item>
     <button (click)="saveItem()">Save to queue

    </button>

  </ion-list>

  `,

  directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES]
})

    export class CreateItemPage {
    @Input() qId: string;
  constructor() {

    console.log(this.qId);
    alert(this.qId);

  }
  saveItem(){

  }
   }
```

I tried to send in data to @Component like this  and   and also this way

Where is the error??

Answer (score 0):

So strange - after i been at this for LONG time ..... i found answer.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.qId);
    alert(this.qId);
  }
```

Seems like values are not set when trying to read them in constructor...its to early.